# Inline \usebox vertical alignment

Tags: listings, vertical-alignment, boxes, inline

As I need to pass a verbatim environment into a command, I use `\savebox` and then render it inline with the rest of the text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\setlength{\textwidth}{500pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-20pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-20pt}

% Define questions environment with framed \question
\newcommand{\questionlabel}{Question }
\newcommand{\restorequestionlabel}{\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{Question }}
\newcommand{\setquestionlabel}[1]{\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{#1 }}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[questions]{align=left,ref=\questionlabel\arabic*,label=\textbf{\questionlabel\arabic*.},wide}
\newcommand{\itembr}{\needspace{10\baselineskip}\item\mbox{}}
\newcommand{\question}[1]{\itembr\begin{mdframed}#1\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\begin{lrbox}{0}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
int* p = (int*) malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}
\question{
    Explain what \usebox{0} does.
}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The `\question` command is used to put the text into an `mdframed`. Since it's declared using `\newcommand`, there is no way to pass in any verbatim environment directly. Using `verbatimbox` is not an option as I need syntax highlighting from `listings`.

The problem is that the resulting text seems to be vertically aligned at the top instead of bottom:

[image: Different bottom lines]

Can I somehow align everything automatically? I know `\raisebox` exists, but I'd need to get to know the height difference somehow.

Comment: Please tell us how the `\question` command is defined, because without it there is not problem.

Comment: you probably want lstinline rather than lstlisting

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want the font that lstlisting uses, rather than computer modern with few words in bold

Comment: lstinline uses the same formatting as lstlisting, but for a one-line inline use

Comment: Any news here? Did you try `\lstinline`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your image. However, `boxpos=t` should be what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{boxpos=t}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{0}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
int* p = (int*) malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

Explain what \usebox{0}; does.

\begin{lrbox}{0}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
SWAP(t, x, y)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

Define a macro SWAP\usebox{0} that exchanges two arguments of type t.

\end{document}
```

I added text to emphasize the correctness of the output.

[image]

On the other hand, `\lstinline` seems much easier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

Explain what \lstinline[language=C]{int* p = (int*) malloc(100 * sizeof(int));}
does.

Define a macro \lstinline[language=C]{SWAP(t, x, y)}
that exchanges two arguments of type t.

\end{document}
```

[image]